# Is it possible to add KDE estimation to hisgram in a pairplot plot with seaborn?

Tags: python, seaborn

I'm ploting a pairplot plot with seaborn (See figure). I would like to add to the histograms the KDE estimations. Is it possible? Besides, is it possible to make the histogram less opaque in order to better see both of them?
Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this might address your requirements

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.set(style="ticks")

df = sns.load_dataset("iris")
p = sns.PairGrid(df, vars=['sepal_length', 'sepal_width'], hue="species")
p = p.map_offdiag(sns.scatterplot)
p = p.map_diag(sns.distplot, hist=True, kde=True, hist_kws={'alpha':0.5})
```

Here is the screenshot..

[image]

Comment: It is exactly what I want! Thanks!